# Deleting a value from many to many field in views.py in django website

Tags: django

I am working on a basic ecommerce django website . My product model has the following:

```
size=models.ManyToManyField(Siz)
```

and this is the size model:

```
class Siz(models.Model):
    size=models.CharField(max_length=3,null=True,blank=True)
    desc=models.CharField(max_length=110,null=True,blank=True)
```

I have added the sizes manually in the django administration. What I want is that Whenever a user orders something the value of the size of the product that he ordered automatically is deleted from the product sizes available. This is my orderitem model that has the field of the selected size.

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    order=models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,)
    size=models.ForeignKey(Siz,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
```

and this is my views that checks when the order (payment for the order) is completed or not.

```
@csrf_exempt
def handlerequest(request, id):
    order=Order.objects.get(id=id)
    items=order.orderitem_set.all()
    form = request.POST
    verify = Checksum.verify_checksum(response_dict, MERCHANT_KEY, checksum)
    if verify:
        if response_dict['RESPCODE'] == '01':
            order.complete=True
            order.save()
        else:
            print(response_dict['RESPMSG'])
            order.delete()
    return render(request, 'handlerequest.html', {'response': response_dict,'order':order})
```

When the order is completed the order.complete is set to true.At that Time I want to deleted the ordered size.Please help me with a way.
Thanks

This is my order model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    date_ordered=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    complete=models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=False)
```

Comment: is there an `Order` model class ?

Comment: added in the question

Comment: there is one problem in your order item model when in future any price is changed by the site that price is also changed in the order too. so do one thing when you store anything in the order item store that with the price too..

Comment: Ok thanks @KishanParmar. Can you help me with this problem too

Comment: you want to delete all order item of the order or you want to delete selected order item of the order

Comment: I want to remove the size of items that the user bought from the size many to many field of the product model

Comment: @KishanParmar also where do I set the price of the order item?

Comment: You have to add one extra field called price in order item and add the price when you add any data in orderitem + i can't able to understand what you want to achieve so can't help you with that